# What is a hobbyist who collects old newspapers called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there an English word for someone who collects newspapers as a hobby eg. a philatelist collects stamps, a ..... collects newspapers.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, maybe there's a name somewhere in [this article](http://www.historicpages.com/nprqna.htm), but I didn't see one.

Comment: But apparently "journalistic ephemerology" is occasionally used for the practice.

Comment: @HotLicks Does that mean that a collector of _journalistic emphemerology_ would be a **journalistic ephemerologist** or possibly a **journalistic ephemerophile**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well!

A ***philatelist***, as you've pointed out, is a person who collects (and studies) stamps.

A ***numismatist*** is one who collects (and studies) coins.

A ***vexillophile*** collects and displays flags.

The funny thing here is that all such words are of recent coinage (less than a century and a half, in fact, most of them).

The fact that there is currently no word for someone who collects newspapers (or newspaper clippings, for that matter) does not mean we couldn't coin one ourselves, right here and now, using the same principles. All you need, really, is one or two Latin or Greek roots which, by the way, do not have to be *exactly* right, just close enough (case in point: "philatelist" is composed of two Greek roots, "phil" (love) and "atelia" (exemption from taxes). The fellow who coined it claimed it was as close as he could get, in Koine Greek (or something) to "stamp."

Well, why not ***diurnophile***?

It has a nice Latinate ring to it, does it not?

Answer (score 1):

## ephemerist

someone who collects items of an *ephemeral* nature such as food labels, postcards, [tax discs](https://www.britishtaxdiscs.co.uk/tax-disc-history.php), newspapers etc.

> **Ephemera** are transitory creations which are not meant to be retained or preserved. Its etymological origins extends to Ancient Greece, with the common definition of the word being: "the minor transient documents of everyday life". Ambiguous in nature, various interpretations of ephemera and related items have been contended, including menus, newspapers, postcards, posters, sheet music, stickers and valentines. […]

> **In 1751**, Samuel Johnson used the term *ephemerae* **in reference to "the papers of the day"** – and is frequently cited as the term's creator. This application of ephemera has been cited as the first example of aligning it with transient prints. Ephemeral, by the mid-19th century, began to be used to generically refer to printed items. *Ephemera* and *ephemerality* have mutual connotations of "passing time, change, and the philosophically ultimate vision of our own existence".
> Source: *Wikipedia*

Collectors and dealers of transitory items joined together to form two associations: [The Emphemera Society](https://https:/http://www.ephemera-society.org.uk/about.html) (England) was founded in 1975 while its American counterpart the [Ephemera Society of America](https://www.ephemerasociety.org/ephemera-collecting-a-growing-field-hard-to-define/) was founded in 1980

Comment: As close as one is likely to get.